# Java generics - use same wildcard multiple times

Tags: java, generics, wildcard

I have a class declaration which uses generics and bounded wildcards:

```
class Factory<T extends Logic<? extends Entity>, 
              U extends DAO<? extends Entity>> 
{
}
```

Basically its a generic factory, which takes a logic interface (T) and returns a configured implementation. In order to instantiate the logic, I take a appropriate DAO class implementing the DAO interface (U).

Both interfaces for logic and DAO are generic as well and take the type of the entity to work with as their type parameter. However, I want to constrain that further, so that DAO and Logic not only have a type parameter which extends Entity, but that they extend the same Entity. The result may look similiar to that:

```
class <X extends Entity> Factory<T extends Logic<X>, 
              U extends DAO<X>> 
{
}
```

Can I achieve that with java generics?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you're close. Do it like this:

```
class Factory<X extends Entity,
              T extends Logic<X>, 
              U extends DAO<X>> 
{
}
```

Alternative

```
class Factory<T extends Logic<?>, 
              U extends DAO<?>> 
{
    // Here, the generic method parameter only requires X
    // to be the same bound at method invocation. However,
    // you will "lose" that information again when the 
    // Factory is returned.
    public static <X extends Entity,
                   T extends Logic<X>, 
                   U extends DAO<X>> Factory<T, U> createFactory(T logic, U dao)
    {
        return new Factory<T, U>(logic, dao);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should also do this if you don't have that already: `interface Logic<T extends Entity>`.

Comment: I think you missed a comma there after Entity. Your solution would work, but is there no solution where I dont have to introduce a third type parameter? Your version of Factory would be created like this: `Factory<MyEntity, MyLogic, MyDAO> = new Factory<MyEntity, MyLogic, MyDAO>();` - right?  @ Thomas: Logic/DAOs type param is already bounded, thats why I feel that the additional type param in Factory for the relationship is superfluous.

Comment: That depends. See my alternative. There you can require `X` to be the same bound for both `Logic` and `DAO`. But once you reference `Factory`, of course, you'll lose that information again, if it is not put in the class `Factory` itself...

Comment: @atamanroman The problem is that the generic types can't reference the generic parameters of each other, yet you'd still want to pass in the same entity class  and not something like `Factory<Logic<FooEntity>, DAO<BarEntity>>` if `FooEntity` and `BarEntity` are not related.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach could be to provide a wrapper (although that's not really elegant ;) ):

```
class Entity{}

interface Logic<T extends Entity> {}

interface DAO<T extends Entity> {}

interface DaoLogic<X extends Entity> {
  DAO<X> getDAO();
  Logic<X> getLogic();
}

class Factory<T extends DaoLogic<? extends Entity>> {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Would the following work.  X would be the "common" type, where Logic and DAO both would use this type.

```
public class Factory<X extends Entity, T extends Logic<X>, U extends DAO<X>>
{
}
```